# Change the Motd and ServerPing in BungeeCord

Tags: java, minecraft, bungeecord

```
import java.util.UUID;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ServerPing;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.event.ProxyPingEvent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Listener;
import net.md_5.bungee.event.EventHandler;

public class MOTD implements Listener {
    
    @EventHandler
    
    public void onPing(ProxyPingEvent e) {
        
        ServerPing ping = e.getResponse();
        ServerPing.Players player = ping.getPlayers();
        ServerPing.Protocol vers = ping.getVersion();
        
        vers.setName("§4 Test");
        
        
        e.getResponse().setVersion(new ServerPing.Protocol( "some random text", 2));
        player.setSample(new ServerPing.PlayerInfo[] {new ServerPing.PlayerInfo("here is some text aswell.", UUID.randomUUID()) });
        
        ping.setDescription("and a whole ton of randomt text here");
        
        e.setResponse(ping);
```

Thats my Code so far. And in the screenshot you will the results.
But i dont want the red "x" with the client out of Date Message.
I want the online thingy with my own Text. Any ideas?
#(if i hover the "text" i see my own text, but if i hover the "ping" i get the OutofDate message.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's fixed code with comments:

```java
@EventHandler

public void onPing(ProxyPingEvent e) {
    ServerPing ping = e.getResponse();
    ServerPing.Players player = ping.getPlayers();
    ServerPing.Protocol vers = ping.getVersion();

    // change version text, but dont change version protocol id
    // because that causes the RED X in server browser
    vers.setName("Some version text");

    player.setSample(new ServerPing.PlayerInfo[] {
        new ServerPing.PlayerInfo("here is some text aswell.", UUID.randomUUID())
    });

    ping.setDescription("and a whole ton of randomt text here");

    e.setResponse(ping);
}
```

Comment: You are right so far, that i had to stop changing the protocol.
But, it wont show me the `vers.setName("Text");` for some reason.

Comment: You can't see version name, unless client/server is outdated. It's just how Vanilla client works...